# Exception thrown when connecting to MySql Serv

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to MySql database and an expcetion is being thrown when the "Open" function is called.

This is my code :

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.Port                    = 5432;
builder.Server                  = "<SERV>";
builder.Database                = "<DBNAME>";
builder.UserID                  = "<USER>";
builder.Password                = "<PASSWORD>";
builder.ConnectionTimeout       = 600;
builder.DefaultCommandTimeout   = 600;
string connString = builder.ToString();
using (MySqlConnection connectionTest = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    connectionTest.Open();
}
```

This is the exception message :

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException occurred
> HResult=-2147467259
> Message=Reading from the stream has failed.
> Source=MySql.Data
> ErrorCode=-2147467259
> Code=0
> Number=0
> StackTrace:
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
> at ProjectName.ClassName.FunctionName(Configuration config) in c:\Users\MyUser\Projects\ProjectName\ClassName.cs:line 66
> InnerException: System.IO.EndOfStreamException
> HResult=-2147024858
> Message=Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
> Source=MySql.Data
> StackTrace:
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
> InnerException:

I already looked for questions about this error and they mention timeout problems but I already increased the timeout in the connection string.

Comment: Not a concrete answer, but with little searching, I think it falls down to what version of connector + MySql you are using (or maybe something else).Maybe reading [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html) helps? Good luck

Comment: Can you share your MySqlConnectionStringBuilder?

Comment: port=5432;server=<SERV>;database=<DBNAME>;userid=<USER>;password=<PASSWORD>;connectiontimeout=600;defaultcommandtimeout=600

Comment: @ergis I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.2 and MySql.Data 8.0.28. Are you saying that these versions are incompatible?

Comment: Port 5432 is commonly associated with PostgreSQL. Are you sure this is a MySQL server you're trying to connect to? If it's Postgres, you'll need to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/.

Comment: The program was working with .NetFramework 4.5 32bits but I was told to change to .NetFramkework 4.7 64 bits that`s when it started giving this error.